# how to redirect to a view on $.AJAX complete - asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax

Ok..i want to redirect a user after the validation check using $.AJAX to a peritcular view... how do i do that ? .. pleae help...

here is my $.AJAX code... EX: i want user redirected to "/Home/Movies" controller action...

if not logged in stay on the same page...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btnLogin').click(function () {
        var email = $('#Email').val();
        var Password = $('#Password').val();
        var postdata =
        {
            "Email": email,
            "Password": Password
        };

        $('.Loading').fadeIn(50);
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CheckLogin","Home")',
            data: postdata,
            success: function (msg) {
                var data = msg.split(':');
                $('#Result').html(data[0]);
                $('.Loading').fadeOut(50);
             },
            error: function (data) {

                $('#Result').html(data);
                $('.Loading').fadeOut(50);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

here is my controller action which is used for checking Login details...

```
 public ContentResult CheckLogin(Users checkuser)
        {
            if (db.CheckUserLoginDetails(checkuser.Email, checkuser.Password))
            {
                return Content("Login Successful:" + checkuser.Email);
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("Login UnSuccessful");
            }
        }
```

also how can i pass a returned results from this view to another view.. in this exmaple if the user is logged in i want to show his email id on the redirected page which is lets say "/home/Movies"

thx in advance

Comment: You should have made a new question instead of editing this one.  The answers no longer make sense based on the current wording.

Comment: I agree.The answers no longer make sense based on the current wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show your loading image before ajax request, and hide on `success` or `error` handlers.

add `<div class="loading">Loading...</div>` to your markup

```
$('.loading').fadeIn(50);
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("CheckLogin","Home")',
    data: postdata,
    success: function (msg) {
        $('#Result').html(msg);
        $('.loading').fadeOut(50);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        $('#Result').html(msg);
        $('.loading').fadeOut(50);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `ajaxStart()` and `ajaxStop()` event handlers in jQuery. You could use these to show and hide a layer with a gif-animation.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

Answer (score 1):

use beforSend and complete attributes.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CheckLogin","Home")',
        data: postdata,
        success: function (msg) {
            $('#Result').html(msg);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $('#Result').html(msg);
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("body").append("<div class=\"ajaxLoader\" id=\"ajaxLoader"\"><div class=\"ajaxAnimation\"></div></div>");
            $("#ajaxLoader").hide();
            $("#ajaxLoader").fadeIn('fast');
        },
        complete: function() {
        $("#ajaxLoader").remove();
    }

   });
```

And specify animation with css

```
.ajaxAnimation {
    background-image: url('images/ajax-loader.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```