# How to show waiting message during sync ajax call in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser

How to show waiting message on sync ajax call in browser ?
I tried code below, turned web server off but "Saving" message is not displayed.

After some time only error event from ajax call occurs, without any progress message.

How to show waiting message to user if sync ajax call is in progress ?

```
var myInfo = '<div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all" style="position: fixed;' +
    'z-index: 10000; margin-top: 2%; margin-left: 2%">' +
    ' <br />' +
    '&nbsp;<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>' +
    '<strong>Saving</strong>&nbsp;<br />' +
    '<br /></div>'
$('#_info').html(myInfo);
$('#_info').show();

$.ajax( 'save',
   {
       async: false,
       type: 'POST'
    } );
```

Comment: It was discussed just today [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299562/how-to-redirect-to-a-view-on-ajax-complete-asp-net-mvc-3/)

Comment: @Samich: My code and answer which link you posted work **only with async** ajax call. In my question I clearly stated that question is about sync ajax call. Add `async: false` option to the ajax call in the link which you posted and note that loading message does not appear anymore.

Comment: just move `$('.Loading').fadeOut(50);` just after your ajax call

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using a synchronous AJAX call and that pretty much locks up the browser until it completes. In particular, the browser won't be able to show your "loading" message before you hit the `$.ajax({async:false})` lockup; for example, watch what this does:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/xAdk5/

Notice that the button doesn't even change back to the unclicked visual state while the AJAX is running?

The solution is to show your loading message, hand control back to the browser, and then lock everything up with your synchronous remote call. One way to do this is to use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout) with a delay of zero:

```
$('#_info').html(myInfo);
$('#_info').show();
setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax('save', {
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        complete: function() {
          $('#_info').hide();
        }
    });
}, 0);
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/zLnED/

Some care will be needed of course as `this` won't be the same inside the `setTimeout` callback as it was outside but that's easy to take care of.

Using `async:false` isn't a very nice thing to be doing to your users though, you should try to avoid it unless it is absolutely necessary (and it rarely is).

Comment: This solution works fine in like 4 of 6 try's on my computer with chrome 25.0. In the other cases it works just like without encapsulation of the ajax call. Why is this and can it be fixed somehow?

Comment: @nilsi: You can try fiddling with the timeout on the `setTimeout` call but really you should pretend that `async:false` doesn't exist and code your application to deal with the asynchronous nature of server communication.

Answer (score 2):

`<div class="loading">Loading...</div>`

Your ajax call:

```
$('.loading').fadeIn(50, function() {
   $.ajax( 'save',
   {
      async: false,
      type: 'POST'
   } );
});

$('.loading').fadeOut(50);
```

Comment: This won't work, the `async:false` will lock up the browser before the loading message comes up.