# How to display 'Loading' when making a 'synchronous' AJAX call in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, synchronous

I want to make sure the result is shown to user, so I make synchronous AJAX call. It's quite simple to display a 'Loading' indicator with asynchronous AJAX (the examples are everywhere), but when I use synchronous AJAX call with XMLHttpRequest, the loading indicator GIF image doesn't show up at all.

Some said that it's impossible to show indicator when doing a synchronous call (block until having response from server). But I just want to ask to see whether there's a way to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's "impossible" because Javascript is single-threaded, and the synchronous call blocks updates to the UI.

However, you may be able to display an animated 'loading' graphic *before* launching the synchronous AJAX call, and removing it upon success or failure. I believe most browsers will be able to continue rendering the animated gif even while technically blocked for the synchronous call.

Comment: Yep. It can work to display the graphic and then use a (very short) `setTimeout` to kick of the synchronous Ajax so that the browser gets a chance to repaint before running the Ajax.

Comment: @nnnnnn this doesn't guarantee that the browser can get a chance to draw. the time spent by browser for drawing is not measurable

Comment: @Paul - yes, but (depending on the browser) just breaking up the code execution with a timeout can be enough to let it start repainting, and once it starts repainting it will probably be OK. The problem is when it doesn't even start repainting.

Comment: @nnnnnn if you use setTimeout, (and thus pass a callback), why not simply use asynchronous ?

Comment: @niahoo - I _would_ use async, but the OP wanted synchronous for some reason so I was just suggesting a possible compromise workaround (where the function delayed by _setTimeout()_ would be the one containing the synchronous ajax code).

Comment: i know you would :) I just pointed out that your proposal negates the advantages of syncronous calls. (I think so because with a timeout, you switch context : the original calling function continues in parallel so it can't catch the return of the ajax fun), i may be wrong

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, see the top answer here:
[How to show waiting message during sync ajax call in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301459/how-to-show-waiting-message-during-sync-ajax-call-in-browser)

> The solution is to show your loading message, hand control back to the browser, and then lock everything up with your synchronous remote call. One way to do this is to use setTimeout with a delay of zero