# How can I have some portions of Ajax occur synchronously, while front end logic occurs asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I have a site I'd like to check through several environments for login credentials, but in the mean time, display a loading gif.

Trouble is, if I make the ajax synchronous or,

```
async: false,
```

then the rest of the page pauses until the credentials are checked.

I tried switching the ajax calls back to asynchronous, it will prematurely display a false negative error that the user isn't logged in, since it hasn't finished checking all environments.

I also tried a kind of band-aid solution with

```
setTimeout(loginCheckFunction, 600)
```

But that's arbitrary timing, and if the user has a slow connection, the false error will persist.

Any ideas on how to make some portions run without waiting for the synchronous Ajax to finish?
Thanks!

edit:
I think my issue is pretty much inadvertently solved by this question:
[How to display 'Loading' when making a 'synchronous' AJAX call in pure JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019078/how-to-display-loading-when-making-a-synchronous-ajax-call-in-pure-javascrip)

edit 2:
I skirted the issue by using the top answer to the above question.  I gave a very small setTimeout function to the beginning of parent function calling the synchronous ajax-based login checks, during which time the 'loading' gif can be launched, and viewed simultaneously while ajax runs.
Per the answer given though, in the strictest sense, it isn't running simultaneously, the browser just provides that illusion.
For future persons maybe running into similar issue, I transitioned from setTimeout being applied on the child function, to setTimeout being applied one level up on its the parent function.

Comment: HTML5Rocks' [tutorial on Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) can be a very interesting read that fits your needs, if you're willing to learn new concepts.

Comment: This is a big change to the question. You might need to revise the tags.

Comment: I removed references to the Chrome extension, so I took off that tag, and also Jquery, because I suppose those tags are especially irrelevant to the heart of the question.

Comment: I am reluctant to delete the question entirely, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried do one ajax call after another ajax call ends?
First you show your loading screen and do the ajax calls one after another ends. In the last call you hide your loading. In this way you parallelize all the ajax call, validating each pass.

[You can use the Ajax Queue plugin](http://foliotek.github.io/AjaxQ/)

Comment: I had been using a for loop to go through an array of ajax endpoint urls.  I reckon I could just hard code them go one by one, I'd been avoiding that, but I will check out that alternative, thankyou!