# Animated gif during script processing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, animated-gif

I have a script called notify_me.php which I run like so:

```
script type="text/javascript">
    //Run notify_me.php script
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#submit").click(function(){
        var d = $('form').serialize();
        $.get('php/notify_me.php',d,function(data){
           $(".container").html(data);
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

and I would like to show a animated loading .gif until the script is printed. The code for that is :

```
<div class="search_load" >
  <span class="searching_font"> Fetching your flight prices...</span><br/><br/>
  <img src="images/searchloading.gif">
</div>
```

How can I write a function that shows the .search_load class during the processing of notify_me.php. The .search_load class should also be shown in the .container div.

Tried some different ways with append(); and appendTo(); but can't seem to get it working.

Appreciate your help on this!

EDIT: I got the .search_load div to show the first time I hit the #submit. The second time it doesn't show att all. This is the problem I'm trying to solve. Any ideas?!

SOLUTION: Guys, I solved it by looking in to @Rohan's link. Check out below. Thank you all!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#submit").click(function(){
     $('#info').show();
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#info").offset().top},'slow');
     $('.container').after('<div class="search_load"></div>');
     var d = $('form').serialize();
     $.get('php/notify_me.php',d,function(data){
       $(".container").html(data);
       $('.search_load').hide();
     });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1. Make your loading div hidden
2. When loading starts, display it using .show() and modifying the CSS so that its placement is correct
3. OnLoaded -> div.hide()

Refer to this: [How to show waiting message during sync ajax call in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301459/how-to-show-waiting-message-during-sync-ajax-call-in-browser)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search_load').hide();
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var d = $('form').serialize();
        $('.search_load').show();
        $.get('php/notify_me.php',d,function(data){
        $('.search_load').hide();
            $(".container").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

You can also hide the div with CSS, so you can remove the line #2:  $('.search_load').hide();

Comment: Hey fonini!Tried this and it works the first time I hit the submit button. The second time the .search_load doesn't show. It is really weird.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the element with Firebug, for example?

Comment: Yeah, although I can't find anything helpfull there. The element doesn't show the second time I click #submit.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#submit").click(function(){
    $(".search_load").show();
    var d = $('form').serialize();
    $.get('php/notify_me.php', d, function(data) {
       $(".container").html(data);
       $(".search_load").hide();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Dear Micha, the code works the first time I hit #submit. The second time the -search_load div doesn't show at all. Any ideas on this?

Comment: @Ismailp I would say that couldn't be... Do you looked in your error console if something else throws an error?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('div.search_load').hide();
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $('div.search_load').show();
    var d = $('form').serialize();
    $.get('form.php', d,
    function(data) {
        $('div.search_load').hide();
        $('.container').html(data);
    },
    'html');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Dear abdullah, this only makes .search_load show once. The second time I hit the submit button it doesn't show again. This is my problem!

Comment: ! Tried it bro, but still shows only the first time I hit #submit. The .search_load div doesn't show the second time :(

Comment: @Ismailp can you please make a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ismailp/UrrCh/ my php script loads content in the .container div. It must have something to do with that becuase my fiddle works...please check it out

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#submit").click(function(){
         var d = $('form').serialize();
         $(".search_load").show();
         $.get('php/notify_me.php',d,function(data){
             $(".container").html(data);
             $(".search_load").hide();
         });
      });
 });
 </script>
```

HTML Changes:

```
<div class="search_load" style="display:none" >
   <span class="searching_font"> Fetching your flight prices...</span><br/><br/>
    <img src="images/searchloading.gif">
</div>
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Still only shows the loading .gif the first time I hit submit. How can I make it show up the second time?