# jQuery Validate ajaxSubmit show hidden div

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validate with ajaxSubmit to post a multipart/form-data form to my CI controller.

```
//Form Submit functions
    $('#newEventSubmit').click(function(s) {
        $("#newEventForm").validate({
            errorClass: "validattion",
            validClass: "valid",
            highlight: function( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
                $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
            },
            unhighlight: function( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
                $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) { },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                var formObj = $(form);
                var formURL = formObj.attr("action");
                var formData = new FormData(this);
                $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                    url: formURL,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data:  formData,
                    mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "HTML",
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                        console.log(jqXHR);
                        console.log(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

My question is this, I have a hidden div which is a Hud that I want to display whilst the ajaxSubmit is processing. `$( "#hud-overlay" ).show();` however when I put it into the click event the form stops processing and if I put this in the `$(form).ajaxSubmit()` code it doesn't fire can any one tell me what I am doing wrong.

NB. I have also tried this, but to no avail.

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
    $( "#hud-overlay" ).show();
});
```

Comment: Perhaps this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301459/how-to-show-waiting-message-during-sync-ajax-call-in-browser

Comment: I have looked at this, but because I am using the Jquery Validation library and therefore their submitHandler it doesn't seem to be playing the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong…

```
$('#newEventSubmit').click(function(s) {
    $("#newEventForm").validate({ ...
```

You do not put the `.validate()` method inside of a click event handler.  The `.validate()` method is only for *initializing* the plugin on your form.

The click event of the `submit` button is captured *automatically* by the plugin.  Typically you would put `.validate()` inside of the DOM ready event handler and then the plugin is initialized when the page is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {     // <- DOM is ready

    $("#newEventForm").validate({  // <- initialize the plugin on the form
        …                          // <- your options, rules, and callbacks
    });

});
```